# Maximal generalized symmetric groups and the tensor product

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, unitary-representations

Let $S(m,n)$ be the generalized symmetric group which is a wreath product of the cyclic group of order $m$, denoted here by $\mathbb{Z}_m$, and the symmetric group $S_n$. A standard unitary representation of $S(m,n)$ is given by the semi-direct product of the $n\times n$ permutation matrices and $n \times n$ diagonal matrices with $m$-th roots of unity entries. (These matrices are sometimes called generalized permutation matrices. They are also monomial matrices.)

For finite integers $m\ge 1$ and $n > 1$ all such unitary matrices form a finite subgroup of $U(n)$ of size $n! m^n$. I'll denote this group of unitary matrices as $M(m,n)$. I'll say that $M(m,n)$ is maximal if the addition of any $U \in U(n)$ where $U$ is not a monomial matrix necessarily generates an infinite order group.

My question is the following:

Let $M(m,n_1)$ and $M(m,n_2)$ be maximal. Does this imply that $M(m,n_1 n_2)$ is a maximal?

Intuition for why this might be (but probably isn't) true. Since $M(m,n_1)\otimes M(m,n_2) \subset M(m,n_1 n_2)$, any non-monomial $U \in U(n_1 n_2)$ that can be added to $M(m,n_1 n_2)$ must not have $U=\Pi_L U_1 \otimes U_2 \Pi_R$ for any $U_1 \in U(n_1), U_2 \in U(n_2)$ and $\Pi$ is any $n_1n_2 \times n_1n_2$ permutation matrix.

Comment: This bounty is running out! Proof (or disproof) of the case with $n_1 =n_2 =2$ will now be given the bounty.